# What is the best way to update thousands of placemarks dynamically in Google Earth?

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

Im using the google earth v1 javascript API to update hundreds of objects moving around in "real-time". I keep track of new, modified, and deleted entities to minimize looping in my javascript while updating placemarks, but still the biggest bottleneck is making the calls to the google earth api. Has anyone else tackled this problem? I've read a bit about dynamically streaming from a KML file on a server, but I need access to the placemark object updates in my javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a bow on this question. Using dynamic KML files is one way to do this if you dont need to do anything complicated with the data other than display it to the user. Because I need to do work on the data inside the webclient, I ended up using json to transfer the data and then using [google.earth.executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739) to execute my google earth api calls in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a v3 of the Google Maps Javascript API, but the Google Earth API is at v1.  It's unclear from your question if you are using both API's, and if so, how you are interacting with the Earth API.

If you provide some code showing how you are doing the updates it would be easier to offer advice on how to optimize.

That said it sounds like using straight KML with incremental Updates is the way to go for your use case, and you can still access individual placemarks using the getElementByUrl() method

Comment: thanks @jlivni, I've corrected the API version information in my question.

Comment: I am definitely using the GE javascript API. The problem is I have an object with complex state information that other GUI components can modify/reference. I use GE as the visualization component; the object can have a placemark and lines associated with it. If I used the KML stream concept, I'd have to store all of the extra state information in the description element of the placemark object associated with the object, and then query the KML layer for each object in order to update my local object's state. I'll take some time to add a generic code version of what Im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/)? It doesn't use the GE plug-in so....